# What transformation do I have to apply to a node before passing it to \uput as a direction angle?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

Consider the following code

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pgfmath}% don't forget this line!
\psset{saveNodeCoors}
\degrees[13]
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,T,J,Q,K}
{
    \pnodes(!3 \j\space neg \pst@angleunit 90 add PtoC){X\i}
    \qdisk(X\i){2pt}
    \uput[!N-X\i.y N-X\i.x atan 1 \pst@angleunit div](X\i){\i}
    %\uput[(X\i)](X\i){\i}
    %\uput[!\psGetNodeCenter{X\i} X\i.y X\i.x atan 1 \pst@angleunit div](X\i){\i}
}
\end{pspicture}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

with the following output.

[image]

But if I use either

```
\uput[(X\i)](X\i){\i}
\uput[!\psGetNodeCenter{X\i} X\i.y X\i.x atan 1 \pst@angleunit div](X\i){\i}
```

I got the following incorrect output.

[image]

According to Herbert's response several decades ago (I don't know exactly where in this site), the pairs (`N-<node>.x` and `N-<node>.y`) and  (`<node>.x` and `<node>.y`) have different transformation matrices.

The question is what transformation matrix do I have to apply to `X\i` node before passing it to `\uput` as the direction angle such that I get the same correct result?

### Update

When the center of the circle is not at the origin, unfortunately `\uput[(NODE)](>NODE){contents}` no longer works.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}  
\pstVerb{/XX 3 def /YY 4 def}

\degrees[12]

\makeatletter
\def\object#1{%
\begin{pspicture}[saveNodeCoors,showgrid](0,1)(6,7)
    \pnode(!XX YY){P}
    \pscircle(!XX YY){2}
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=13]{0}{12}{2 t \pst@angleunit PtoC YY add exch XX add exch}{R}
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\Rnodecount}
    {%
        \pstVerb
        {
            /ALPHA {\i\space} def
            %/ALPHA {N-R\i.y N-P.y sub N-R\i.x N-P.x sub atan 1 \pst@angleunit div} def
            %/ALPHA {\psGetNodeCenter{R\i}\psGetNodeCenter{P} R\i.y P.y sub R\i.x P.x sub atan 1 \pst@angleunit div} def % IT CANNOT BE USED!
            %/BETA {ALPHA 90 1 \pst@angleunit div sub} def
            /BETA {\i\space 90 1 \pst@angleunit div sub} def
        }%
        \ifcase#1
            \psset{linecolor=red}
            \uput[\i]{!BETA}(R\i){$R_{\i}$}
        \or
            \psset{linecolor=green}
            \uput[!ALPHA]{!BETA}(R\i){$R_{\i}$}
        \or
            \psset{linecolor=blue}
            \uput[(R\i)]{!BETA}(>R\i){$R_{\i}$}
        \fi
        \psline(!XX YY)(R\i)
    }
\end{pspicture}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {0,...,2}{\object{\x}}
\end{document}
```

**case 0**

[image]

**case 1**

[image]

**case 2**

[image]

Comment: I cannot sleep without knowing the solution of this legacy problem.

Comment: How can you award a 500 point bounty while having only 67 points?

Comment: @Ingo: Because I still have about 10000 points but nobody knows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desired behavior is achieved with the prefix `>` for the position node, i.e. using `\uput[(X\x)](>X\x){\x}`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\degrees[13]
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
\foreach \x [count=\xi from 0] in {A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,T,J,Q,K}
{
    \pnodes(!3 \xi\space neg \pst@angleunit 90 add PtoC){X\x}
    \qdisk(X\x){2pt}
    \uput[(X\x)](>X\x){\x}
}
\end{pspicture}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is equivalent to the third version with

```
\uput[!\psGetNodeCenter{X\x} X\x.y X\x.x Atan 1 \pst@angleunit div](>X\x){\x}
```

Seems like this syntax was introduced exactly for this kind of `\uput` behavior, see `texdoc pst-news10`.

Comment: How about the third version?

Comment: See my edit. As you said in the question: `\uput[(X\x)]` is equivalent to `\uput[!\psGetnodeCenter{X\x}...`.

Comment: Please kindly revisit my question update, apparently `>Node` syntax does not work for center that is not the origin.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\degrees[13]
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
\psforeach{\x}{A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,T,J,Q,K}{%
    \pnode(3;\the\psLoopIndex){X\x}
    \qdisk(X\x){2pt}
    \nput[labelsep=12pt]{(X\x)}{X\x}{\red\x}
    \pcline[linestyle=none](0,0)(X\x)\ncput[npos=0.7,nrot=:R]{\x}
    \nput[labelsep=-15pt,rot=\the\psLoopIndex]{\the\psLoopIndex}{X\x}{\green\x}
    \uput{20pt}[\the\psLoopIndex](X\x){\blue\x}
    \psline[linestyle=dotted](3;\the\psLoopIndex)
}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I think your code is only for rotations about  the origin. Could you make it more general in which the center of rotation is not at the origin `(0,0)`?

Comment: There are _two_ rotating angles: `\nput[rot=<origin>]{<rotate around node>}{<nodename>}{<text>}`