# Picture indicating the fifth roots of unity

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to have the unit circle, centered at the origin, on the Cartesian plane drawn.  The origin is to be marked with a dot and labeled "O" and five dots are to be drawn on the circle, one on the x-axis, and the others at `k(2\pi/5)` radians from the positive x-axis for each integer `1 \leq k < 5`, and they are to be labeled "`w_{k}`".  Arrows are to be drawn from the origin to each `w_{k}`, too. One angle is to be drawn and labeled - the one from the positive x-axis to the ray through `w_{1}`.

I have included some of the code.  It starts with the following commands.

```
\tikzset{mydot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt}}
```

Is there a manual that explains each of these commands?  I guess that this is instructing LaTeX how to make the dots indicating the coordinates each time "`\mydot`" is in the code.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
mydot/.style={
  fill,
  circle,
  inner sep=1.5pt
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]


% the coordinates of the vertices
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (w_{1}) at (\cos(2\pi/5), \sin(2\pi/5));

% the axes
\draw[help lines,->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
\draw[help lines,->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);

% labelling the vertices
\node[mydot,label={below:$O$}] at (O) {};
\node[mydot,label={right:$w_{1} = \bigl(\cos(2\pi/5), \sin(2\pi/5)\bigr)$}] at (w_{1}) {};


% the arcs for the angle
\begin{scope}[gray]
\draw[->]
  (1,0) +(0:0.5cm) arc [radius=1cm,start angle=0,end angle=2\pi/5] node[midway,right] {$2\pi/5$};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To learn more about TikZ read [pgfmanual.pdf](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). Via the macro `\n` you can adjust the order of the root to be taken.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}% for \Re and \Im
\def\n{5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  dot/.style={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}
  ]
  \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[below] {$\Re$};
  \draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[left] {$\Im$};
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) circle (1);

  \node[dot,label={below right:$O$}] (O) at (0,0) {};
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\n} {
    \node[dot,label={\i*360/\n-(\i==\n)*45:$w_{\i}$}] (w\i) at (\i*360/\n:1) {};
    \draw[->] (O) -- (w\i);
  }
  \draw[->] (0:.3) arc (0:360/\n:.3);
  \node at (360/\n/2:.5) {$\alpha$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

For `1 < n < 13`:

> [image]

Comment: Shouldn't the labels `w_2` and `w_3` be placed symmetrically? They are conjugate, after all. Likewise for `w_1` and `w_4`.

Comment: @egreg Yes, you're right. I also was unsatisfied and looked up in the documentation how to write a Kronecker delta. Now the angle is computed by `\i*360/5-(\i==5)*45`.

Comment: +1 Now you have just to generalize it to the *n*-th roots for any *n* > 2. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Done, but the label placement doesn't really work as expected, e.g. for the angle 270° the label isn't placed below the node.

Comment: The graph for the fifth roots of unity is nice.  I have questions about the code.  Instead of having "def/n{5}" in the preamble and "\foreach \i in {1,...,\n}" in the TikZ environment, can I have "\foreach \i in {1,...,5}" in the TikZ environment?  In the optional argument, you type "dot/.style={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}".  I looked at the pgfmanual.pdf that you suggested. The first mention of "dot/.style" is on page 630.  The syntax is not described. What is this command telling LaTeX to "draw" and to "fill"?

Comment: @user143462 To get only fifth root change every occurrence of `\n` to `5` and remove `\def\n{5}`. In the argument of the `tikzpicture` I define a new `style` with the name `dot`. What it does is, it applies all options given in the braces to the path where I apply it. For a tutorial see section "2.8 Adding a Touch of Style", for the reference see section "82.4.4 Defining Styles" in the `pgfmanual.pdf`.

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\def\Object#1{%
\begin{pspicture}[saveNodeCoors,arrows=->](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pscircle{2}
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=\numexpr#1+1]{0}{360}{2 t PtoC}{w}
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\wnodecount}{\psline(w\i)\uput[!N-w\i.y N-w\i.x atan](w\i){$w_{\i}$}}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\foreach \n in{1,2,...,10}{\Object{\n}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: More about angle (made from node expression) passed to `\uput` [can be found here(click)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154815/19356).

Answer (score 1):

With some additional notations

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
 \usepackage{amsmath}% for \Re and \Im
  \def\n{8}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}
]
\draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[below] {$\Re$};
\draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[left] {$\Im$};
\draw[help lines] (0,0) circle (1);   
\node[dot] (O) at (0,0) {};
\node[label={above right:$+i$}] (I1) at (0,1) {};
\node[label={below right:$-i$}] (I2) at (0,-1) {};
\node[label={above right:$1$}] (U1) at (1,0) {};
\node[dot,label={above right:$-1$}] (I2) at (-1,0) {};

\foreach \i in {1,...,\n} {

  \node[dot,label={\i*360/\n-(\i==\n)*45:$w_{\i}$}] (w\i) at ( \i*360/\n:1)   {};
   \draw[->] (O) -- (w\i);
  }
  \draw[->] (0:.3) arc (0:360/\n:.3);
    \node at (360/\n/2:.5) {$\alpha$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a picture. I'd also recommend not using `\def\n{8}`, but something like `\newcommand{\lastnumber}{8}` (or any other command name): with `\def` you risk redefining important commands, which could lead to puzzling errors or output. Just to be picky: `\Re` and `\Im` don't need `amsmath`, which is recommended anyway when math typesetting is involved.