# Polygon with balls as corners

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a regular polygon with tikz. It should be something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193402/picture-indicating-the-fifth-roots-of-unity) but i want the dots to be balls like 
`\shade[ball color=black]`.

Another problem I have is that I cannot run the code in the link in the `\documentclass{scrreprt}`. Coud you help me out?

Thank you in advance

tech

Comment: You can definitely run the code in Henri Menke's answer in `scrreprt`, I just tested, but you need of course to add `\usepackage{tikz}`. If that doesn't fix it, then we really need some more information about your setup and what happens when you run the code (which error is reported).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example draws a regular n-gon. Change the `8` in `\def\n{8}` to select the number of edges.

[image: Result of tikz code below]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\n{8}
\foreach \i in {1, ..., \n}{
    \node[circle, shade, ball color=black, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=2pt] (ball\i) at (\i*360/\n:1) {};
}
\foreach \i[remember=\i as \lasti (initially \n)] in {1, ..., \n}{
    \draw (ball\lasti) -- (ball\i);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution with PSTricks. `curvepnodes` is useful to define an array of nodes for any given number of nodes and curve functions. For example, we can use it to make an array of 12 nodes on a circle. `Offset` is provided as the rotation offset.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+10}{10}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showpoints,dotscale=6](-4,-4)(4,4)
    \pstVerb{/Offset \i\space def}%
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=13]{0}{360}{3 t Offset add PtoC}{A}
    \psnpolygon[linecolor=red](0,\numexpr\Anodecount-1){A}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With Alain Matthes [`tkz-berge`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-berge), it's easy to do it:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Shade]
\SetVertexNoLabel
\grCirculant[RA=3]{8}{1}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]